# In Xcode 3.2.3 NSDate returns year 2553. How to fix

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos

I'm using Xcode 3.2.3 and Xcode 3.2.2. In Xcode 3.2.3 `[NSDate date]` (or any NSDate methods) returns 2553 year and current month, year, time. It's ok in 3.2.2. I tried to find where it can be placed at default values but I didn't find that option. I removed and installed it again but it didn't help too. What should I change? 
 Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you show some example code?

Comment: Show us how you arrive to the 2553 year so that we can tell you what's wrong.

Comment: I think it is not in code.However code like:
  NSLog(@"%@",[NSDate date]); 
will return 2553-08-13 12:10:37 +0300

Comment: Presumably your clock is wrong.

Comment: My clock is ok. I use 2 versions(!) of X-code on my Mac, and one of them returns me wrong year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calender may be set to "Buddhist"

2553 BE. BE is Buddhist Era

Go settings >

> General
>   international
>   calendar
>   Gregorian

That should do the trick.